# How can I check wether a (Google maps API) map has loaded?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have started building an android application that focuses on a map from google-play-services-libs. When I start the app, it takes a while for the map to load from the gray grid to showing the map image.

I'd like to move/play around a bit with the map when it has fully loaded the part that is currently on screen. I have however been unable to find a way to programmatically check whether the map has loaded.

How can I achieve this?

In short:
From a instance of `GoogleMap`, how do I determine if it is actually showing something?

Comment: There's a function "boolean onDraw" in Overlay class. I'm not sure whether or not its last parameter has been revised or not. It deals with this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a OnCameraChangeListener on your map.  The onCameraChange call will be called when the map's tiles are initially loaded.

```
  this.map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {
      isMapReady = true;
      map.setOnCameraChangeListener(null);
    }
  });
```

Comment: I am no longer working on this project, but this seems like it would work, so accepting this answer

Answer (score 0):

**chckReady()** function checks whether the map is ready or not

```
public class MapView extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {

        private GoogleMap mMap;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.ui_settings_demo);
            setUpMapIfNeeded();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            setUpMapIfNeeded();
        }

        private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
            if (mMap == null) {
                mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                        .getMap();
            }
        }

        private boolean checkReady() {
            if (mMap == null) {
                return false;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think it's not really what I asked for (Correct me if I am wrong). What I wanted to know, was that when I have the map object loaded (so that I see a grid and the controls), but there is no "content" loaded, only the grid. I'd like to know when the "content/image" has loaded to the user